# Cipher Suites order enforced by IIS

Tags: ssl, iis, cipher

We are trying to get approved from a vendor that requires cipher suites order to be processed in this way:

```
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

We use Windows Server 2016 with IIS 10. If we use a wildcard certificate for the website, ssllabs.com only shows the RSA cipher. So, we bought an EV ECDSA certificate just for our website (no wildcard), installed it (which produced 2 separate certificates (ECDSA and RSA), and bond 443 to the ECDSA certificate. Ssllabs.com will only show the ECDSA cipher but no RSA cipher.

We have changed the order in

```
Local Group Policy-> Administrative Templates->Network-> SSL Configuration Setting-> SSL Cipher Suites Order
```

to have the above required order.

For someone that knows nothing about cipher suites and very little about certificates, is there a way to process the cipher suites in the order required? How would this be accomplished? Is it a configuration setup? Is it possible in a Windows environment?

Comment: You need to have a word with the vendor.  As you've just found out, you can either send an ECDSA certificate, or an RSA certificate, but not both.  It's not a limitation of IIS, but of the protocols.

Comment: Or don't use IIS to host the application.

Comment: @garethTheRed+ you can _send_ only one leaf cert (plus its chain) on a handshake, but some servers can _have_ more than one cert and choose which to send based on the ciphersuite order. In particular OpenSSL supports this and Apache httpd can use it, although I don't know about other OpenSSL-using programs; similarly Java (JSSE) supports it and Tomcat can use it. AFAIK schannel (and IIS) can't. That said, the requirement doesn't really make sense and I would push back if satisfying it is costly.